# TCP - What happens when RTO is too small?

Tags: tcp

I am studying TCP and I have this doubt. Let's think that the client becomes congested too quickly and the server never gets the ACKs before the RTO expires. So the server retransmits unnecesary a lot of segments.
How does the server acknowledge this and set the RTO to a larger value?

Thanks!

Comment: Eh? It would need to set it to a *larger* value, and it does that based on the observed RTT when the ACKs finally come in.

Answer (score 0):

https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt

"    An Example Retransmission Timeout Procedure

```
  Measure the elapsed time between sending a data octet with a
  particular sequence number and receiving an acknowledgment that
  covers that sequence number (segments sent do not have to match
  segments received).  This measured elapsed time is the Round Trip
  Time (RTT).  Next compute a Smoothed Round Trip Time (SRTT) as:

    SRTT = ( ALPHA * SRTT ) + ((1-ALPHA) * RTT)

  and based on this, compute the retransmission timeout (RTO) as:

    RTO = min[UBOUND,max[LBOUND,(BETA*SRTT)]]

  where UBOUND is an upper bound on the timeout (e.g., 1 minute),
  LBOUND is a lower bound on the timeout (e.g., 1 second), ALPHA is
  a smoothing factor (e.g., .8 to .9), and BETA is a delay variance
  factor (e.g., 1.3 to 2.0).
```

"